# Сравнение строки и числа в php

Tags: php, типы-данных

Есть код с условием

```
foreach ($data as $kk => $vv){
                
                if(trim($vv) === "" || (int) $vv === 0){
                    //Здесь
                }
    }
```

Нужно проверить если $vv string на не пустую строку и если $vv float или int на равно 0

Проблема в том что php считает строку "Привет я строка" == 0
Как написать нужное условие?

Comment: Вопрос: а почему у вас могут быть строки, а могут быть числа?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский такой массив $data

Comment: Ну так `is_string` и соответствующие сравнения.

Comment: " такой массив $data " -  Это не ответ.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский таков путь

Comment: @АлексейШиманский такие данные в этом массиве их нельзя поменять , вообще это строки из БД соответствующих типов

Comment: "вообще это строки из БД соответствующих типов" --- как я вижу, вы делаете что-то не то и не так. И я бы в таком случае пересмотрел бы логику. И не списывать всё на "надо быстро срочно")

Comment: `$a = '';
echo $a ? 'true' : 'false';
$a = 0;
echo $a ? 'true' : 'false';
$a = 0.;
echo $a ? 'true' : 'false';` - это три false

Answer (score -1):

```php
foreach ($data as $kk => $vv) {
    if (
        (is_string($vv) && trim($vv) === "")
        || (is_numeric($vv) && $vv === 0)
    ) {
        //Здесь
    }

}
```